# nul terminating a int array

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I was just experimenting with a int array. And something just came to my mind. Can I nul terminate it. For example, I am using a 0 to nul terminate. However, 0 could well be a valid value in this array.

The code below will terminate after the 5. Even though I mean 0 to be a valid number. However, I could specify the size of the array. But in this case, I don't want to this as I am just interested in this particular problem.

Many thanks for any advice,

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void test(int *p);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {30, 450, 14, 5, 0, 10, '\0'};

    test(arr);

    return 0;
}

static void test(int *p)
{
    while(*p) {
        printf("Array values [ %d ]\n", *p++);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only store unsigned values, -1 would be a good terminator. You can replace `while(*p)` with `while(*p+1)` for this.

Comment: BTW, the `0` and `'\0'` mean exactly the same thing when initializing `int`s.

Comment: @schnaader: You mean "If you only store *positive* (or *non-negative*) values...".

Comment: @Oli: Yes, thanks for the catch. Can't edit anymore :(

Comment: @David Thornley: In C, `0` and `'\0'` mean exactly the same thing *always*, since character constants have type `int`.

Comment: @caf:  You're right, of course.  Either I was thinking of C++ despite the context or there was too much blood in my caffeine stream.

Comment: Does not look like a big mystery to me - dereferencing p to 0 will terminate the while loop - am I missing something ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, no. Technically nul characters are equally valid in strings too, it's just a convention that we use them for marking the end of a string, and all the standard library functions expect that. There are "double nul-terminated" strings that end in `\0\0` for cases where a string needs to contain a `\0`, but then of course you have the problem of not being able to store `\0\0` in the string.

If you don't want to store an array's size separately (or use trickery like `sizeof`), you need to come up with a sentinel that can be stored in that type but you know won't be part of the array; you could use `45` as long as you're sure `arr` won't have that as a valid value, it just needs to be unique

Comment: How do you know that your chosen magic number will still be a valid magic number later?  You could use the maximum value for an integer as your sentinel value; that's a good convention in C# or Java.  But do you know that that can always be a good sentinel value?

Comment: @David:  There is no always-good sentinel value, and sometimes there is no good sentinel value for a given location.

Comment: If using a sentinel is not an option you will have to store the count of bytes in a separate variable (this is common practice, too).

Answer (score 3):

In order to use a sentinel value, obviously you have to find a value that is not otherwise valid data. That is one of the drawbacks of using a sentinel (the other being the linear search required to find the length). How does something like `0xFFFF` work for you?

If this were C++, I'd suggest making a class with an associated length member (or better yet, just using `std::vector`). For C you should probably just keep the separate length variable yourself. You can get fancy and put it and the array together in a struct if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, \0 is the same as 0, so if you have a zero in your array your code will mistake that for the array's end:

```
int arr[] = {30, 450, 14, 5, 0, 10, '\0'};
                             ^ this is the end of the array
```

Edit: note that by "end of the array" I mean the conceptual end of the array as defined by your algorithm, rather than the actual extents of the data laid out in memory by the C programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can also change your sentinel from `\0` to `\\0`. And, accordingly, a slight modification in the condition for `while` loop will get you around your problem.

```
while(*p != '\\0')
```

Now, `0` will not be treated as terminator for the integer array and the whole array gets printed.

Comment: This method can work, so long as `23600` is not part of the array before the intended end.