# Why don't numeric arrays end with a '\0' or null character?

Tags: c, arrays

Why don't the numeric arrays end with a null character?

For example,

```
char name[] = {'V', 'I', 'J', 'A', 'Y', '\0'};
```

But in case of numeric arrays there is no sign of null character at the end...

For example,

```
int marks[] = {20, 22, 23};
```

What is the reason behind that?

Comment: `char[]`s don't have to end in `'\0'` either...

Comment: [Relative to that](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/)

Comment: All of answers below does not answer the question asked.

Comment: Yes I know mate they didnt answered correctly but I got the point from someone's answer that why '\0'  is not included at the end of numeric arrays :)

Comment: Ask yourself this question: Can you think of a reason you would want an array of integers where at least one of them is `0` ? For example, `int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4};` The value `0` as an `int` has usefulness. There is no-such-usefulness in an "string" in the C-sense beyond its purpose as a terminator, and as such we were blessed with the zero-terminated string concept. I can think of no other way to quantify it beyond that (honestly). And many, including myself, wish the pascal-style (length-prefixed) string would have been adopted instead.

Comment: Why all you guys posting that "array of chars is not a string" as answers? It is absolutely true, and it was written by Dennis Meng in very first comment. But that by no means answers the question asked!

Comment: @Drop; Because it related to the question asked. In my answer I clarify that why `\n` is not used for arrays.

Comment: I have this array ended in 0: `int arr[] = {3, 4, 0};`
So, what?

Comment: Why 4 upvotes for a bad formulated question? What's the point?

Comment: By convention, in C, a character "string" ends with a "null" character.  This is because the string's length is not "externally described".  Any array of anything is useless if you don't know it's length.

Answer (score 34):

The question asked contains a hidden assumption, that all `char` arrays do end with a null character. This is in fact not always the case: this `char` array does not end with `\0`:

```
char no_zero[] = { 'f', 'o', 'o' };
```

The `char` arrays that must end with the null character are those meant for use as strings, which indeed require termination.

In your example, the `char` array only ends with a null character because you made it so. The  single place where the compiler will insert the null character for you is when declaring a char array from a string literal, such as:

```
char name[] = "VIJAY";

// the above is sugar for:
char name[] = { 'V', 'I', 'J', 'A', 'Y', '\0' };
```

In that case, the null character is inserted automatically to make the resulting array a valid C string. No such requirement exists for arrays of other numeric types, nor can they be initialized from a string literal. In other words, appending a zero to a numeric array would serve no purpose whatsoever, because there is no code out there that uses the zero to look for the array end, since zero is a perfectly valid number.

Arrays of pointers are sometimes terminated with a NULL pointer, which makes sense because a NULL pointer cannot be confused with a valid pointer. The `argv` array of strings, received by `main()`, is an example of such an array.

Comment: Yes I know that but my question was Why we do not include '\0' in numeric arrays ?

Comment: @VijayChauhan Because there's no need for them there. As the answer says, the `\0` in character array only serves to make the array a valid C string. If there is no requirement to make it a string (as is obviously the case for non-`char` arrays), a trailing 0 is useless.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question is exact: `Why the numeric arrays does not end with a null character?`

Comment: @Drop Sometimes seemingly exact questions are unanswerable, such as "do your parents know you're bald?" (if you're not bald). The phrasing of the OP's question contains a hidden assumption that char arrays do end with a null character, which is not (necessarily) the case. The answer explains this in some detail, and if you think you can answer the question better, feel free to submit an answer of your own.

Comment: "no code out there that uses the zero to look for the array end",  bit of a bold statement that! I think from all the code in the world they probably is some somewhere that does just that.

Comment: @PeterSW Of course, there are wild things out there :) but do note that I was specifically referring to arrays that contain zeros.

Answer (score 8):

An array can end in anything that is a valid value of the array element type. But only a `\0` terminated `char` array is called a string.

For example

```
char name[]={'V','I','J','A','Y'};
```

Valid, but not a string, the limit is that you can't use it in functions expecting a string like `strlen` etc.

---

To clarify from OP's comment below, by the C standard, any character literals like `'a'`, `'1'`, etc, including `'\0'` are type `int`. And you can put a `'\0'` at the end of an `int` array like this:

```
int arr[] = {20, 22, 23, '\0'};
```

But people usually don't do that because it's conventional that `'\0'` is only used to terminated strings. The above code is equivalent to

```
int arr[] = {20, 22, 23, 0};
```

Comment: Thankx bro :)
And I got a conclusion from ur reply that why numeric arrays doesnot hav '\0' at the end.The simple reason behing this is that '\0' is not integer type hence it cant be included in numeric arrays :)

Comment: @VijayChauhan:- Yes thats correct. Also check out a related thread on Stackoverflow:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998983/nul-terminating-a-int-array

Comment: @VijayChauhan Well, actually, by the C standard, any character literals are type `int`, including `\0`.

Comment: @YuHao yes i know that but I asked why we donot include '\0' in numric arrays can u give proper reason for that..someone told that '\0'=>0 hence its useless to use '\0'.So was that the proper reason for that???

Comment: @VijayChauhan I never use `'\0'` myself. I quickly grew away from that habit when porting code *littered* with such hand-set terminators from ANSI to Unicode. Hundreds of files globally replacing `'\0'` with `L'\0'` made me realize half-way through "duh. just replace it with `0` and let the compiler sort it out with proper promotion".

Comment: @VijayChauhan That is correct. `'\0'` is the same as `0`. And it's not unique. The character `'A'` is the same as the integer `65` in any ASCII machine. Like I said, it's just conventional that `'0'` has this special meaning of terminating strings.

Comment: okay if you say so..but again the problem arises..Suppose we hav to store the marks of 4 students in which stud1 secured 10 ...stud2 secured 20 and stud3 secured 0 and we hav not entered the marks of stud4...so if we use another 0 or '\0' at the end then wat will be the outcome of that situation ...clarify me

Comment: @VijayChauhan I think you mean you are using a value as a guard? That is useful in some situations and `0` is one common guard in certain problems.

Comment: @YuHao, you are the first men in this thread, who at last found the real question asked. Now read first post, the first line =)

Answer (score 5):

A *string* ends with a 0 terminator, but a *string* is not the same thing as an *array*. We use arrays to *store* strings, but we also use arrays to store things that are *not* strings.  That's why arrays *in general* don't automatically have a 0 appended to them.

Besides, in any generic array of `int`, 0 may be a valid (non-sentinel) value.

Answer (score 4):

You can make an `int` array end with `0` as well, if you wish:

```
int iarray[] = {1, 2, 3, 0};
```

Since `'\0'` and `0` are exactly the same, you could even replace the `0` above by `'\0'`.

Your confusion might be due to the automatic insertion of `'\0'` in a declaration such as:

```
char s[] = "hello";
```

In the above, the definition of `s` is equivalent to `char s[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};`.  Think of this a a convenient shortcut provided by the C standard.  If you want, you can force a non-zero terminated char array by being explicit about the size:

```
char s[5] = "hello";
```

In the above example, `s` won't be `NUL` terminated.

Also note that character literals in C are of type `int`, so `'\0'` is actually an `int`.  (Also further, `char` is an integral type.)

Comment: Last sample: it also won't compile. clang:  ("Initializer string for char array too long.")

Comment: @WhozCraig But it is valid C. See [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=ansi#nonstrings)

Comment: @WhozCraig The C standard says: "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the terminating null character **if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @AlokSinghal its my warnings + warnings-as-errors settings. I'm always compiling with them  cranked, and this was picked up by them. I sincerely apologize.

Comment: @WhozCraig no problem.  It's interesting that clang warns about this case.  Nothing in the standard is stopping it from trying to be extra helpful :-).  I tried with gcc and with my standard compiler warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra` plus a bunch of others), it doesn't warn about this.

Comment: @AlokSinghal He cannot (generally) mark end of `int` array with 0, because 0, in context of program, can be a valid value. I think that's what was question about.

Comment: @Drop It's a very poorly phrased question.  `0` is a valid `char`.  In one particular case, that being a C string, `0` is used as a string terminator (sentinel value).  This case is no different from using `0` as a terminator for an `int` array if the array is supposed to contain only positive values.

All the people who answered this question already know all of the above.

Answer (score 3):

There are three, maybe four decent ways of tracking an array's length, only two of which are common in C:

- **Keep track of the length yourself and pass it along with the pointer.**

  This is how arrays typically work.  It doesn't require any special formatting, and makes sub-array views trivial to represent.  (Add to the pointer, subtract from the length, and there ya go.)

  Any function in the standard library that works with non-string arrays expects this already.  And even some functions that mess with strings (like `strncat` or `fgets`) do it for safety's sake.
- **Terminate the array with some "sentinel" value.**

  This is how C strings work.  Because nearly every character set/encoding in existence defines `'\0'` as a non-printable, "do nothing" control character, it's thus not a typical part of text, so using it to terminate a *string* makes sense.

  Note that when you're using a `char[]` as a *byte array*, though, you still have to specify a length.  That's because *bytes aren't characters.*  Once you're dealing with bytes rather than characters, `0` loses its meaning as a sentinel value and goes back to being plain old data.

  The big issue is that with most fundamental types, every possible arrangement of `sizeof(type)` bytes might represent a valid, useful value. For integral values, zero is *particularly* common; it is probably one of the most used and most useful numbers in all of computing.  I fully expect to be able to put a `0` into an array of integers without appearing to lose half my data.

  So then the question becomes, what would be a good sentinel value?  What otherwise-legal number should be outlawed in arrays?  And that question has no good, universal answer; it depends entirely on your data.  So if you want to do such a thing, you're on your own.

  Besides the lack of a decent sentinel value, this approach falls flat with non-character types for another reason: it's more complicated to represent subsets of the array.  In order for a recursive function to pass part of the array to itself, it would have to insert the sentinel value, call itself, and then restore the old value.  Either that, or it could pass a pointer to the start of the range and the length of the range.  But wait...isn't that what you are trying to avoid?  :P

For completeness, the two other methods:

- **Create a struct** that can store the array's length along with a pointer to the data.

  This is a more object-oriented approach, and is how arrays work in nearly every modern language (and how vectors work in C++).  It works OK in C iff you have an API to manage such structs, and iff you use that API religiously.  (Object-oriented languages provide a way to attach the API to the object itself.  C doesn't, so it's up to you to stick to the API.)  But any function that wasn't designed to work with your structs will need to be passed a pointer (and possibly a length) using one of the above two methods.
- **Pass two pointers.**

  This is a common way to pass a "range" in C++.  You pass a pointer to the start of the array, and a pointer just past the end.  It's less common in C, though, because with raw pointers, `(start,length)` and `(start,end)` represent the same data -- and C doesn't have the iterators and templates that make this so much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

**You do not have to have a `'\0'` char at at the end of character array!** This is a wrong assumption. There is no rule which says you do. Characters (`char` type) are exactly like any other kind of data.

You do have to have a null terminated char array if you want to **print the array using standard `printf`**-family functions. But only because those functions depend on the ending of the character array - `'\0'` char.

Functions often have rules concerning the kind of data they expect. String (`char[]`) functions are not exception. But this is not a language requirement, it's the API you're using which has these requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to end C strings with `'\0'` since this is how the library knows where the string ends.
**The `NUL`-termination is what differentiates a char array from a string** (a `NUL`-terminated char-array). Most string-manipulating functions relies on `NUL` to know when the string is finished (and its job is done), and won't work with simple char-array (eg. they will keep on working past the boundaries of the array, and continue until it finds a `NUL` somewhere in memory - often corrupting memory as it goes).

Comment: +1, but the term `NULL` is not appropriate. It is `NUL`, zero or better just `0`. `NULL` is a null pointer constant.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. We all know why is zero-termination for. The question is exact: `Why the **numeric** arrays does not end with a null character?`

Answer (score 2):

Char array ends with special char `'\0'` so that it can be treated as string.
And when you are manipulating string there must be some way to tell the length(boundary) of that string.

Look at function prototype of  [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

How does it know to copy how many chars from source to destination? The answer is by looking at the position of `'\0`'.

The `'\0'` char is prominent when dealing with string as a `char *`. Without `'\0'` as an end marker you wouldn't have been able to treat `char *` as string.

Answer (score 1):

An array of char not necessarilly ends with \0.

It is a C convention that strings are ended with \0.
This is useful to find the end of the string.

But if you are only interested in holding data that is of type char, you can have a \0 at end or not.

If your array of char is intended to be used as a string, you should add \0 at the end of it.

**EDIT**: What is ended by \0 are the string literals, not the array of char.
The question is ill formulated.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays by themselves do not have to be `0\` terminated, it is the usage of the character arrays in a specific way that needs them to be `\0` terminated. The standard library functions which act on character arrays will use the `\0` to detect end of the array and hence treat it as a string, this behavior means the users of these functions will need to follow the `\0` termination precondition. If your character array usage doesn't use any such functionality then it doesn't need the `\0` terminator.

Comment: "Arrays by themselves do not have to be 0\ terminated". And I can say that it would be very useful, to have such a mark in the end of array. Question asked was: why we do not have such a mark.

Answer (score 0):

An example to take the point that how \0 will confuse if taken in a integer array:-

```
int marks[]={20,22,23,0,93,'\0'};
                      ^
```

So now your array will assume that 0(marked) is an end of the array which is not true.

`\0` is usually used to terminate a string. In string `\0` is regarded as the end of the string.

In your example you dont need to terminate it with '\0'

Found a very interesting [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998983/nul-terminating-a-int-array) post:-

> At the time C (and the languages that it was derived from) was
>   developed, memory was extremely limited, so using only one byte of
>   overhead to store the length of a string was attractive. The only
>   popular alternative at that time, usually called a "Pascal string"
>   (though also used by early versions of BASIC), used a leading byte to
>   store the length of the string. This allows the string to contain NUL
>   and made finding the length need only one memory access (O(1)
>   (constant) time). **However, C designer Dennis Ritchie chose to follow
>   the convention of NUL-termination, already established in BCPL, to
>   avoid the limitation on the length of a string caused by holding the
>   count in an 8- or 9-bit slot, and partly because maintaining the count
>   seemed, in our experience, less convenient than using a terminator.**

Also check a related post:- **[nul terminating a int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998983/nul-terminating-a-int-array)**

Comment: @kotlomoy; I think its intentional.

Comment: We all know it cannot terminate with zero. The question is **why**?

Comment: @Drop:- Ok so you have downvoted all the answers here. Anyways i have tried to update my answer after you have downvoted. Hope that makes it better. And you can remove your downvote :(

Comment: @RahulTripathi, your post is very interesting, but it still not answers the question asked.

Comment: @Drop:- I have explained with the help of an example what OP has asked. Is  that wrong to get downvoted? :(

Comment: @RahulTripathi sorry, I see the example and see that we cannot use zero-termination, and how it failed to find proper end of array. But I still cannot see the answer on question "Why is that so?". And answer is very simple, and has nothing with C. Just a common sense.

Comment: @Drop:- No issues. And I agree that it is a common sense and nothing to do with C. I tried to answer as best as I can! :)

Comment: @Drop OP asked: "Why the numeric arrays does not end with a null character ?" And this answer is one of two which actually answers the question (other one is yours). Example solely shows "Why the numeric arrays does not end with a null character" and explains "the reason behind it". So I don't see the reason to downvote.

Answer (score -3):

**We have a convention:** special character `'0'` with numeric code `0`, marks end of the string.

But if you want to mark end of `int` array, how will you know is that `0` is a valid array member or end-of-array mark? So, in general, it is not possible to have such a mark.

**In other words:**

The character `'\0'` (but not character `'0'`, code `48`) **have no any sense** in context of text string (by convention, it is a special character, that marks end), so it **can** be used as end-of-array mark:

Integer `0` or `\0` (which is the same), are valid integer. It **can have sense**, and that is why it **cannot** be used as end-of-array mark:

`int votesInThisThread[] = { 0, -1, 5, 0, 2, 0 }; // Zeroes here is a valid numbers of upvotes`

If you'l try to detect end of this example array by searching `0`, you'll get size of 0.

That is what question about?

Comment: `0` is a "valid" `char` as well.  Nothing in the C language stops me from doing `char s[] = "hello\x00world";`  (Can you guess what `sizeof s` would be in this case?

Comment: @AlokSinghal I'm going to stab at that and say 12-chars. It is, after all, a terminated literal ("over"-terminated, just to be, you know, sure =P).

Comment: @Alok, characters `0` (ACSII code `48`) and `\0` (code `0`) are not the same.

Comment: @Drop `0 == '\0'` and `'0'` is the character literal for which the ASCII value is 48.  Since the question is talking about `char` arrays, and not necessarily strings, `'\0'` *can* be a valid character in such an array.

Comment: @AlokSinghal, That exactly what I wrote. BTW, the question is not about `char` arrays. It is about **why** `int` arrays doesn't have end-of-array mark. Read first post carefully, find question marks in it, so you will know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Drop `char` arrays don't have end-of-array mark either.  Also, `'0'` is not the same as `0`.  Similarly, `'\0'` is not the same as `\0`.  `\0` doesn't even mean anything unless it's in quotes.

Comment: @drop I guess u got my question :)  Everyone is saying abour strings bla bla bla but they are not getting what the question actually meant for ? I m hoping for a bull's eye answer .. mate do u hav any idea regarding this ???

Comment: @Vijay, well, I've explained my ideas it in my answer above =) The basic thing is that `0` have no sense in a line of text (it has a special meaning), but it can be a valid integer number in context of int array (as any other integer).

Comment: @Drop: Especially in older versions of C, it may sometimes be useful to have string literals with embedded zero bytes.  The `string` methods won't see parts of the literals which follow the first zero byte, but other methods which know the purpose of the data to which string literal points can use the whole thing.  As an example, if code needs to write out the byte sequence 1,2,3,0,3,2,1 it could do something like `write_data("\x01\x02\x03\x00\x03\x02\x01", 7);`.  It would be the responsibility of the code using the string literal to know how long it is, since the zero byte won't say.

Comment: @Drop: Newer dialects of C allow "in-line" array declarations which may reduce the need to abuse string literals in such fashion, but in older C dialects string literals are the only construct which says "give me a reference to a constant array holding certain content" that can be used *within* an expression.