# Passing a char array with \0 char to other function

Tags: c, arrays, null

I'm trying to pass a char array to another function but some of the chars may be \0.
The array is output of 'xor' of two strings, and therefore an example of \0 could be:
\0 = 'A' ^ 'A'

If I for example try sending arr[3] = {\0,1,2} to func foo:

```
void foo(char* c){
...

}
```

Then c will be equal to "" .

What would be the correct way to do it in C?

Edit:
I eventually solved it using @AntonH and @Cody grey tips, I sent the size of the string I wanted to copy and used it in my foo function.

for example for concatenating my string in function:

```
void catMsg(char* dest, char* source, int sourceSize)
{
    int i,destLen;
    destLen= strlen(dest) ;
    for(i=0;i<sourceSize-1;i++)
        dest[destLen+i] = source[i];
    dest[destLen+i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: It works that way if you use it as a string. If you use it as an array of data, send the size along (`void foo(char* c, int size)`) and loop according to the size of the array.

Comment: It is no problem, you just need to pass the *length* of the array as a parameter, since there is no sentinel value that can be used to determine it automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nul terminating a int array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998983/nul-terminating-a-int-array)

Comment: Yes I'm using it as a string.
I will later concatenate this string to another string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise mine and @cody-gray's answer.

The `null` string terminator is only applicable if you're using it as a string.

If you're using it as an array of `char`, then it's a value like any other.

To be able to use it, you will need to pass the size of the array as an additional parametre, and loop through the array using the size, rather than according to any terminator.

```
void foo(char* c, int size){
    ...
}
```

Comment: So i guess that if I want to concatenate it later to another string I'll have to loop over all the chars. right?
isn't there a way I could pass the array as reference? somthing like:
(&arr)[3]

Comment: @MaxGold You can't use the C string functions, because these are based on the `0` terminating the string. You would have to use something like `memcpy()`, but this requires a size, which is not automatically passed in C functions.

Comment: Thanks,
sounds like a good idea.
I'll reply later on how it went.

Comment: @MaxGold Okay, keep us posted.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers.
I have eventually used your tip for sending the size of string the and concatenated using the string as array of chars.